# Using a page's functions in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which is injecting some code into a web page (I know that part's working), which is trying to call a function that is part of the original web page. The function works fine from the console, but gives an error when the extension calls it. I assume this is some sort of security feature, but is there a way to get around it? Please help!

PS. It's just for one website, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with content scripts. Chrome extensions content scripts live in isolated worlds, meaning they share DOM, but have separate JavaScript sandboxes. Read more [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment):

The workaround to this is to inject a `<script>` into the DOM of the page, but that code won't have privileges to call any `chrome.*` APIs.